# How to use Google API with Django on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm looking for a while now for a good code example about how tu use the [`google-api-python-client`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) in [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) on [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/).

I found out in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440349) that the very cool [decorator](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#Decorators) isn't fit for Django.

There is a [code example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/SampleApps#Django_Samples) for the `google-api-python-client` but neither does it make use of Google App Engine nor is it at all documented.

I can't be the only person, that wants to use django on GAE and implement the API. I would be very grateful for some wisdom.

Comment: Why do you think that fully-worked-out Django example is no good for GAE? As far as I can tell, it has exactly what you need.

Comment: @DanielRoseman not really GAE has it's own users API (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers) which can be domain bound.
Despite that, the example uses the `login_required` decorator. That requires a SQL database to be set up. I would rather use GAE's NDB storage.